# SQL Select CASE-WHEN - How to remove formatting from telephone numbers

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have a SQL Select statement that creates a table from a number of fields.  I'm using the CASE/WHEN to change some of the values but I'm stuck on how to format the results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3, field4,
CASE meta_value WHEN 'male' then 'M' WHEN 'female' THEN 'F' etc.
```

The telephone numbers that are returned may have other characters that I would like to remove, i.e.:

```
(404) 202-2039
404-202-2039
1-404-202-2039
```

I would like to return only the numbers with no spaces or other characters, hyphens, parentheses, etc:

```
4042022039
```

Any ideas on how to best accomplish this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database (and version) you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...? String functions are highly database-specific.

Comment: No `+` for international numbers `+44 (0)123 456 789`?

Comment: You will need `REPLACE()` function to convert unwanted characters into empty strings. If your database engine supports `REPLACE_REGEX()` type of functionality you will be able to get rid of all unwanted characters in one call.

Comment: I'm using MySQL btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '') clean_phone_number
```

Comment: @DavidS.: `select field1, field2, regexp_replace(phone_number, '[^0-9]', '') clean_phone_number, case meta_value when ... then ... end from ...`

Comment: So it seems I'm stuck on MySQL 5.7, thanks to my hosting provider.  I don't see where REGEXP_REPLACE is implemented or supported.  Thanks a bunch guys!